# Python to C code?

Tags: python, c

I wrote a program in python (using standard python libraries) long ago. Now I need to write the same program in standard C due to the lack of python support for that device.

Please suggest me programs or conversion method to convert that python code into C code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shedskin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) could do the trick:

> Shed Skin is an experimental compiler,
>   that can translate pure, but
>   implicitly statically typed Python
>   programs into optimized C++. It can
>   generate stand-alone programs or
>   extension modules that can be imported
>   and used in larger Python programs.

Comment: Shedskin is the best option, but unfortunately, not all modules in the SPL work

Answer (score 1):

So there is a C library for the device? You should be able to [wrap the C library](http://docs.python.org/extending/) with a Python module.

You can also use [cython](http://www.cython.org) to write the interface to the C code